# CSS Changes made, lost mobile functionality

Tags: css, mobile

I just have a question regarding a site that I'm working on,

http://sportsentertainmentattorney.com/

My problem is, I made some css changes in wordpress using the edit css page, specifically these changes.

```
 @media (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 959px) {
 .ciref.outline-outward.left {
margin-left: 28%;
}

.right {
 margin-left: 28%;
 }

 #print_radio {
word-wrap: break-word;
 }

#blog-text-title {
line-height: 36px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}

 #tony_media.custom_title1 {
font-size: 52px !important;
line-height: initial;
padding: 1px 3px 3px !important;
}

.title2 .text {
Margin-left: 24%;
}

.title2 h2 em {
margin-top: 10px;
}

strong {
line-height: initial;
}
}
```

After these changes were made, half the site lost functionality in its mobile version.

The main broken parts are , under "Why Choose Us" those 9 Icons should respond to a touch click creating a red border as it does in the desktop mode. Also that slideshow which consists of Allison strong and others, none of those links in that slideshow are clickable either.

When I inspect element in mobile version, the wrong class gets chosen, I think that might be the problem. Every part that doesn't work falls under the same class "h2#print_radio.front_h2" which it shouldn't be. I just don't know how I would go about testing that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance. Also any tips regarding improving this site would be greatly welcome to. Thank you

Comment: Have you validated your code?

Comment: Yes I have, it brings up some errors but nothing directly related to the this issue

Answer (score 0):

It's now WordPress, it's your CSS:

`#devn-320955` is missing the class of `.container_full`.

`#devn-413264` needs a clearfix or `overflow:hidden`.